# Two resources using the same resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

Well, I didn't know how to title this. This was my best guess. Here's my problem:

I'm having `Issues` and `Reviews` controllers. Both of them should have a `Comments` controller nested.

Do I have to generate two separate scaffolds like `icomment` for the `Issues` and `rcomment` for the `Reviews` or is there a way to use the resource simultaneously for both?

These two controllers are already nested, so i guess it would get pretty messy to maintain this. What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Why not just make `nested routes` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave it at the same level as the two commentable objects:

```
namespace :whatever
  resources :comments
  resources :issues
  resources :reviews
end
```

And force the requests to `/whatever/comments` to have values for the `params[:commentable_id]` (for Create, Update and Edit) and the `params[:commentable_type]` (for all CRUD) ;)

---

An example of a nested form for the Issue model:

```
# issues controller
before_filter :set_issue, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def set_issue
  @issue ||= params[:id].present? ? Issue.find(params[:id]) : Issue.new
end

# view _form
form_for @issue do |f|
  f.text_field :name
  f.fields_for @issue.comments.new do |ff|
    ff.text_field :content
  end
  f.submit "Save!"
end

# Issue model
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

Comment: Mr Yoshiji once again to the Rescue :) Could you edit your answer with an example of a form for a) issues b) reviews so i can study it ?

Comment: Mind joining me for a quick  talk ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54658/parsing-a-document-rails